# Is DynamoDb UpdateExpression with ADD to increment a counter transactional?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Do I need to use optimistic locking when updating a counter with ADD updateExpression to make sure that all increments from all the clients will be counted?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#API_UpdateItem_RequestSyntax

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you would still call it a transaction if that is the only thing you are doing in DynamoDB, it is a bit confusing the terminology.

IMO it is more correct to say it is `Atomic`. You can combine the increment with other changes in DynamoDB with a condition that will mean it won't be written unless that condition is true, but if your only change is the increment then other than hitting capacity limits there won't be any other reason (other than an asteroid hitting a datacenter or something of the like) why your increment would fail. (Unless you put a condition on your request which turns out to be false upon writing). If you have two clients incrementing at the same time, DynamoDB will handle this somebody will get in first.

But let's say you are incrementing a values many many times a second, whereby you may indeed be hitting a DynamoDB capacity limit. Consider batching the increments in a Kinesis Stream, whereby you can set the maximum time the stream should wait upon receiving a value that processing should begin. This will enable you to achieve consistency within x seconds in your aggregation.

But other than extremely high traffic situations you should be fine, and in that case the standard way of approaching that problem is using Streams which is very cost effective, saving you capacity units.